# Unity3D: The namespace "Google: could not be found

Tags: unity-game-engine, dll, google-cloud-platform, package, nuget

I have installed the packages using

```
Install-Package Google.Cloud.Speech.V1 -Version 1.2.0
```

It shows

```
Package 'Google.Cloud.Speech.V1.1.2.0' already exists in project 'Assembly-CSharp'
```

I have checked the packages folder, all the dlls are present

[image]

Scripting Runtime verison: .NET 4.x

Scripting backend: Mono

Api Compatibility level: .NET 4.x

Why cant I access Google namespace?

Comment: Show the code and explain what you are trying to do. Then we can help with recommendations.

Answer (score 0):

Installing packages yourself in the Packages folder like you seem to do, doesn't work with Unity. You should use the **Package Manager** window inside Unity to manage the packages that your project uses.
Another way of using third-party libraries is putting them in a folder called "Plugins" inside the Assets folder of your project.

That said, I think the error message you're mentioning ('Package already exists') means the packages *are* being referenced in your project, but it looks to me that you've installed multiple versions of the library. It may help to remove the ones that are not needed like the netstandard ones.